# How would I return N number of IEnumerable<bool> value with a single method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, yield-return

Task:

- Create a public interface called IBoolS with a single method called
  GetBools: Parameter int N, return value IEnumerable .
- Create a public class called Generator that implements this interface
  with a boolean property called ValueToGenerate, and the GetBools
  method here should return N pieces of ValueToGenerate.

This is what I've tried so far:

IBoolS.cs:

```
public interface IBoolS
{
   public IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N)
    {
        //what goes here? yield return something, but what?
    }
}
```

Generator.cs:

```
public class Generator : IBoolS
{
    private bool ValueToGenerate;

    //GetBools(N pieces of ValueToGenerate);, but should be an integer number
}
```

Comment: Nothing goes into an interface. It just defines the signature of the method, nothing else

Comment: @ThomasWeller Since C# 8.0 it is possible (default implementation)

Comment: Maybe. This task looks like a programming assignment which focuses on early semester programming language knowledge. @Akuhei, if you want to know about most modern C# 8.0 stuff, please mention that.

Comment: @SirRufo while it is true (since C# 8.0), I still don't use it and don't recommend using it. 
In my opinion (and to have a non confusing convention), interfaces should be just contracts, default implementations can go into an abstract or non abstract base class if needed.

Comment: No, it really is just a programming assignment. So should I write only this in the interface?

public IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N);

Comment: Yes, exactly. And then put the `yield` stuff into the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface is just a *declaration*, a *contract* for the class(es) which implement it:

```
public interface IBoolS
{
   IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N);
}
```

`class` *implements* the interface:

```
public class Generator : IBoolS
{
    // Let's have a property instead of field: which value is generated
    public bool ValueToGenerate {get;}

    // Do not forget a constructor - we have to set ValueToGenerate
    public Generator(bool valueToGenerate) {
      ValueToGenerate = valueToGenerate;
    }    

    // Interface implementation: we generate N bool values
    public IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N) {
      // Input validation
      if (N < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(N));

      // Shorter version is
      // return Enumerable.Repeat(ValueToGenerate, N);
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        yield return ValueToGenerate; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `nameof('N')` is a syntax error. Perhaps you mean `nameof(N)`?

Comment: @Blindy: thank you! I'm sorry for the typo

Comment: And why ++i instead of i++?

Comment: @Aksi: `++i` instead of `i++` my old habbit: in time of *old* when C compiler, source code and exe must have fit 640k *optimizers* wanted help and `++i` was *faster* then `i++` when in `for` loop. Now, optimaizers are smart enough and `++i` and `i++` are equal

Comment: Ah okay :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need is `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
public interface IBoolS
{
   IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N);
}

public class Generator : IBoolS
{
    public bool ValueToGenerate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N) => Enumerable.Repeat(ValueToGenerate, N);
}
```

Comment: Side note: `public bool ValueToGenerate { get; init; }`, please, note `init;` instead of `set;` is an alternative if we want immutable version

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation (not a performant one though):

```
public interface IBoolS
{
    IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N);
}

public class Generator : IBoolS
{
    private bool _valueToGenerate;
    
    public Generator(bool valueToGenerate) {
        _valueToGenerate = valueToGenerate;
    }

    public IEnumerable<bool> GetBools(int N) {
        foreach (var n in Enumerable.Range(0, N)) {
            yield return _valueToGenerate;
        }                        
    }
}
```